How to get index last position in Handlebars each helper?
I know that this's the way to display the index of an array inside the 'each' helper:
{{#each array}}
  {{@index}} 
{{/each}}

My question is how to display the array length instead. Something like:
    {{#each array}}
      {{array.length}} 
    {{/each}}

By the way, the above code doesn't work. I put many things there, but nothing worked out yet.

What you are trying to do would be possible with a path (../) to "step-up" a context level. Within the #each, the context is the array item at the current index. You must step-up a level to get the array. Therefore ../array.length would work.

You can just use @last
{{#each array}}
  {{#if @last}} this is the last item {{/if}}
{{/each}}

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each
